# "ohne von Gott" in der Lutherbibel

Tags: meaning

In the book I'm reading, I came across this Bible quote from the *Epistle to the Romans* (13, 1) :

- Jedermann sei untertan der Obrigkeit, die Gewalt über ihn hat. Denn es ist keine Obrigkeit **ohne von Gott**;…

I was struck by the bit in bold.  My guess is that the sentence is missing a part that is implied, maybe *zu sein*, but I'm not sure.

The verse is quite close to the Latin we find in the *Vulgate* :

- *Omnis anima potestatibus sublimioribus subdita sit.  Non est enim potestas nisi a Deo*

Perhaps the *Vulgate* is in its turn close to the original Greek that Luther is supposed to have been translating from?  I can't say because my Greek is non-existent.

Is this type of structure something that can be expected in other contexts than the Bible?

Comment: Generally, Luther and any famous German philosopher are bad choices of lecture for students of the German language. They are heavily outdated and not even native speekers do normally understand everything they wrote. Whenever you have to ask about a structure you find in the "Luther Biebel", it's safe to assume that it is not in common use and won't be generally understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an outdated usage of [*ohne*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ohne) in terms of the conjunction [*außer*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/au%C3%9Fer#2).

> Denn es ist keine Obrigkeit *ohne* von Gott ...
>   
>   →
>   Denn es ist keine Obrigkeit *außer* von Gott ...

Today, one would write something like

> Denn es gibt keine Obrigkeit, außer [die Obrigkeit] von Gott ...
>   
>   <sub>(But there is no authority but [the authority] of God ...)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Bible translations most often want and some would say would need to try to follow the original renderings as close as possible.

In this case it *feels* to us moderns like an elliptical construction, one that leaves out a *now* expected part of speech that strictly speaking isn't necessary. It is not necessary in the original Greek and only optional in German or English. For easier reading modern translation might insert the implied part.

This is what [*Luther* wrote, in 1545:](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Neue+Testament/Der+Brief+des+Paulus+an+die+R%C3%B6mer/R%C3%B6merbrief+13)

> JEderman sey vnterthan der Oberkeit / die gewalt vber jn hat. Denn es ist keine Oberkeit / on von Gott / Wo aber Oberkeit ist / die ist von Gott *verordnet.*

Which in the [current translation after Luther in 2017 reads](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/LUT/R%C3%B6mer13)

> Jedermann sei untertan der Obrigkeit, die Gewalt über ihn hat. Denn es ist keine Obrigkeit außer von Gott; wo aber Obrigkeit ist, ist sie von Gott *angeordnet.*

Other German translations follow this usage. Like the Catholic Einheitsübersetzung, the Zürcher Bibel or the Elberfelder, etc.

That [means the original Greek](https://www.bibelwissenschaft.de/online-bibeln/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/lesen-im-bibeltext/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/55/130001/139999/ch/6fc7149c7508c01cdaedac8311c1f273/)

> <sup>13.1</sup> Πᾶσα ψυχὴ ἐξουσίαις ὑπερεχούσαις ὑποτασσέσθω. οὐ γὰρ ἔστιν ἐξουσία εἰ μὴ ὑπὸ θεοῦ, αἱ δὲ οὖσαι ὑπὸ θεοῦ τεταγμέναι εἰσίν.

it has to be read as

> [Denn alle staatliche Gewalt kommt von Gott](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/Ne%C3%9C/R%C3%B6mer13)

[Or](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/apostolic/romans/13.htm)

```
ου          γαρ  εστιν    εξουσία   ει μη   από  θεού 
verneinend, denn da gibt  *Macht    außer   von  Gott.*
No          for  there is *authority unless from God*


αι δε           ούσαι     εξουσίαι     υπό  του  θεού  τεταγμέναι εισίν
und diejenigen  seienden  *Mächte      durch     Gott  sind befohlen.*
and the ones    being     *authorities by        God   are ordered.*
```

Compared to English renderings:

> NIV: [for there is no authority except that which God has established. The authorities that exist have been established by God.](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/NIV/Romans13) 
>   ESV: [For there is no authority except from God, and those that exist have been instituted by God.](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/Romans13)
>   KJV: [For there is no power but of God: the powers that be are ordained of God.](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/KJV/Romans13)

Perhaps it is easier to see the pattern when using the [Elberfelder translation:](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/ELB/R%C3%B6mer13)

> Denn es ist *keine staatliche Macht außer von Gott,*
>   und die *bestehenden sind von Gott **verordnet**.*

Again in English from a reverse interlinear version:

> (Let every person be subject to the governing authorities, )
>   for there is no authority except by God,
>   and those that exist are put in place by god.
>
> <sub>–– W. Hall Harris III & Michael W. Holmes & Rick Brannan: "The Lexham English Bible.  English-Greek Reverse Interlinear New Testament (With Strongs Greek-English Glossary)",Logos Bible Software, 2010.</sub>

Comment: I don't get the point of the NATO example. Yes, it contains the sequence *ohne von* but *ohne* governs *Auftrag* and *von einer amtlichen Beschaffungsstelle* depends on *erteilt*, whereas in *ohne von Gott*, *ohne* governs *von Gott*?

Comment: Da από *apo* Kognat zu *ab*, En *off* etc. ist, wäre "fern ab von" wohl die nächste Übersetzung, nur wäre dieser Ausdruck mittelbar. *abseits von* passt. Als deutscher versteht man aber *durch Gott*. Fraglich war aber *ohne*. μη *me* ist sicher das Negierungspartikel (hey, stimmt sogar, obwohl ich zuerst *ne* gelesen hatte). Wichtig dabei: "μή is the negative of thought or wish". *ει* ... das passt hinten und vorne nicht, die Übersetzung *ist keine* muss überliefert sein und *ei me* quasi als Negation von εἰμί *eimí* "sein" gehandelt worden sein.

Comment: Translating the individual particles with a dictionary gives *wenn nicht [von / ab] Gott*, that does make sense, grammatically. Still, the optative mood expressed by *me* could better translate to Konjunktiv "bestehe" instead of "ist". That threw me off. Sorry for the rant.